# A $4\times4$ Grid Coloring Problem

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

Consider a set of 16 points arranged in a $4 \times 4$ square grid formation. Prove that if any 7 of these points are coloured blue, then there exists an isosceles right-angled triangle whose vertices are all blue.

This problem came in RMO(India) 2023, my Solution goes like I am considering that let there be no such right-angled Isosceles triangle and considering the $2\times 2$ squares that mean the $3\times 3$ grids and going by the fact that we can color at most two vertices of any square blue out of the four and going with the max coloring and taking cases and showing that in every case we are getting a contradiction.

But the main problem with my solution is that I have to consider several cases. So I was wondering if we can solve this using PHP or some better way and also was wondering if we could generalize it.

Comment: Note that in your method you would also need to include squares whose edges are not vertical or horizontal. For example, if the points are labelled $(x,y)$ where $x,y\in[0,3]$, then the points $(0,1),(1,0),(2,1),(1,2)$ form a square. $(0,2),(2,3)(3,1),(1,0)$ would be another example.

Comment: Yes @SaiMehta I have considered those as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution? I don't see how it can be completed, unless you are truly looking at a ton of cases. (So maybe it's that you don't have a complete solution?)

Comment: $$\begin{array}{cccc} \cdot&\bullet&\cdot&\bullet\\\cdot&\bullet&\cdot&\bullet\\\bullet&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\\bullet&\cdot&\bullet&\cdot \end{array}$$is a good example of why considering only triangles with vertical and horizontal sides is not sufficient.

Comment: To avoid a blue isoceles right triangle, at most two of the center four vertices can be blue, so the other five must be on the outside. Only two of them can be on the outside corners. So at least three must be center-outside. At most two of those can be vertices of the same $\sqrt 5$-sided square, so the other $\sqrt 5$ sided square has at least one. This breakdown may have fewer cases to check than what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my approach. Fill in the details where necessary.
IRT = Isosceles Right Triangle because I'm lazy.

**Step 0:** Obviously if 4 points form a square, then any 3 of those points form an IRT.
In particular, if there is no IRT, then at most 2 of those points are blue. We use this idea repeatedly (without mention).

**Step 1:** Consider the following coloring

$\begin{array} { c c c c }  
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & 4 & 2 \\
2 & 4 & 4 & 3 \\
1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array} $

Notice that the points with the same number form a square.
For a given color, if any 3 of those points are blue, we get a IRT.
For a given color, if no points are blue, then by PHP on 7 points with 3 colors, some other color will have at least 3 blue points, so we get an IRT.
Thus, the distribution of blue points has to be $2, 2, 2, 1$ (for some ordering of the colors).
**In particular, we can conclude that (at least) one of the points in the center square (formed by color 4) must be blue.**

**Step 2:**  Claim: If a $3 \times 3$ grid with the center point colored blue has no IRT, then there are at most 3 blue points (which includes the center).

Sketch of proof (it's just casework): Suppose 1 blue point is in the middle of the edge (WLOG first row). Then, we cannot pick any other point in the first two rows. If we pick 2 points from the third row, then they form a blue IRT with the center point.
Else, if there are no blue points at are in the middle of the edge, then  we can pick at most 2 corners.
In either case we have at most 3 blue points.

**Step 3**: From step 1, one of the inner points is blue WLOG  $(2, 2)$ marked as $ \times$. Consider the following coloring:

$\begin{array} { c c c c }  
a & a & a & b \\
a & \times & a & c \\
a & a & a & d \\
d & c & b & c \\
\end{array} $

Suppose there is no IRT, then

- At most 2 of a are blue from step 2
- At most 1 of b is blue
- At most 1 of c is blue
- At most 1 of d is blue

Hence, at most 6 points are blue.

Thus, if 7 or more points are blue, we must have an IRT.

---

Notes

- From the approaches I've seen online (Youtube videos), its often very long and convoluted.

  - I'm not convinced that they have a proper solution, but there's often the language barrier in understanding them.
  - I've not seen my approach being presented (I can't find any official solution either.)
- Here is an example to show why considering triangles that arise from complete squares in the grid is insufficient.

  - From a structure avoider-finder POV, this is what finally caused me to focus on $b \times b$ and $d \times d$ in Step 3. Then I backtracked the rest of the solution (even though the build up seems obvious in hindsight).

$$\begin{array} { c c c c }
\cdot & \cdot & \times & \times \\
\cdot & \times & \cdot & \cdot \\
\times & \cdot & \cdot & \times \\
\times & \cdot & \times & \cdot \\
\end{array} $$

- I've seen claims that for an $n \times n $ grid with $2n-1$ points colored blue, there must be an IRT.

  - Misha showed in the comments that this is not true for $n = 5$.
  - I encourage you to try the $n = 3$ case. (Hint: Build off of step 2 for a one-step-to-complete solution.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov That triangle is part of a complete square, so I've deleted the comment.  I added another example, where the triangle is formed by $(1, 4), (3, 3), (2, 1)$. To complete the square, we need $(0, 2)$ which isn't in the grid.

Comment: Thanks, I see now.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the following shows that $2n-1$ points are not enough when $n=5$: $$\begin {array} {ccccc}
\times & \times & \times & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \times & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \times \\
\times & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \times \\
\cdot & \times & \cdot & \cdot & \times
\end {array}$$

Comment: @MishaLavrov I concur. Thanks!!

Comment: I think it generalizes for all $n>5$. (It's the same as the $n=4$ case with no complete-square triangles in the answer; that one has some "sporadic" triangles, which disappear for $n>4$.) When $n=7$, even 14 points do not suffice: $$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\times&\times&\times&\times&\times&\cdot&\cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\times&\cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\times\\
\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\times\\
\cdot&\times&\cdot&\times&\cdot&\cdot&\times\\
\times&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\times\\
\times&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot
\end{array}$$